# this pointer in lambda-capture by reference

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

```
struct CL
{
    int i;
    void fnc()
    {
        [&this](){i=1;};  // (1) error
        [&](){i=1;};      // (2) ok
    }
};
```

Here is 1st case which doesn't work, but second case does. Why is that?
I see Standard 5.1.2/1:

> *capture:*
>       *identifier*
>       *& identifier*
>       *this*

(i.e. *&this* doesn't exist)

And 5.1.2/15:

> An entity is captured by reference if it is implicitly or explicitly
>   captured but not captured by copy

In second case "this" doesn't captured by copy according 5.1.2/14:

> **An entity is captured by copy if it is implicitly captured and the
>   capture-default is =** or if it is explicitly captured with a capture
>   that does not include an &

But how can I capture "this" pointer by value *explicitly*? Or is it possible only implicitly with *default-capture* & ?

Comment: the very last line should answer your question. `or if it is explicitly captured with a capture that does not include an &`…

Comment: It makes no sense to capture `this` by reference - you can't modify it, or take its address. You can explicitly capture it by value like `[this]`, if you are so inclined.

Comment: `this` can only be captured by value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Formally, `[&]` does indeed capture `this` by reference, per **5.1.2/16** "An entity is *captured by reference* if it is implicitly or explicitly captured but not captured by copy." But that doesn't matter, because

> **5.1.2/18** ... If `this` is captured, each odr-use of `this` is transformed into an access to the corresponding unnamed data member of the closure type, cast (5.4) to the type of `this`. [Note: The cast ensures that the transformed expression is a prvalue. —end note]

So for `this`, capture-by-copy and capture-by-reference are indistinguishable. For all practical purposes, `this` is always captured by copy.